# How to bypass AWS ElasticSearch size of HTTP request payloads

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a AWS ES instance with a [10MB Maximum Size of HTTP Request Payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html), and I have some records that I need to add with more than 10MB of size, so I would like a way that maybe I can keep populating a field once it is already created inside the ES index, so I can keep pushing data after it was created (like updating the field).

I am doing something like this for creation:

```
curl -XPUT 'https://myinstance.amazonaws.com/index_name/doc_type/<item.id>?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "title": <title>,
    "description": <description with more than 10MB>,
    "date": <mydate>,
    "extra_id": <extra_id>,
}
'
```

Is this possible? Maybe keep including fields, or update a field pushing more data to it.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a one off data loading activity then temporarily scale your instance to `m3.xlarge.elasticsearch` to be able to send more than 10 MB payload requests. Once your data is all loaded then scale back to original instance type.

Or if you need to regularly send > 10 MB payload requests then scale the instance size to `m3.xlarge.elasticsearch` permanently.

OR split your data such that it is < 10 MB per request.

Comment: ...OR switch to ES Cloud for more flexibility